# Wildfly server doesn't start under Windows environment

Tags: jboss, wildfly, application-server, wildfly-9, appserver

I am using `Wildfly 9` under both `Ubuntu` an `Windows` servers. Sometimes, I need to restart the servers but after I stop the server, I cannot start it again. There is a red message box saying `Server start failed`. The detailed message is:

```
WFLYCTL0158: Operation handler failed: java.lang.IllegalStateException
```

I cannot stop `Wildfly` because there is a bug on Windows preventing the user from stopping Wildfly server through Services. The process stucks at `Stopping` but it never stops the Wildfly service. I have to restart Windows itself to make it work again.

Anyone facing this problem? How can I overcome this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is how I got around the "stopping" issue.
To kill the windows service without having to reboot windows, create a batch file call it killwindowsservice.bat or whatever. Put the following in it.

```
set SERVICE=%1
echo Killing Service %SERVICE%
FOR /F "tokens=3" %%A IN ('sc queryex %SERVICE% ^| findstr PID') DO (SET pid=%%A)
IF "!pid!" NEQ "0" (
    taskkill /f /t /pid !pid!
)
```

Just call your script with the name of the windows service. So for me I call my Windows Services the name of my application server instance. So for eaxmple "Server01".

So for me I would call it like:
killwindowsservice.bat Server01

And the script will kill the windows service.

The Windows service scripts that come with Wildfly 8.x+ DO NOT work on Windows 2012/2012 R2. I have not gotten them to work. I went and grabbed the jbosssvc.exe from a previous version of JBoss and customized the Windows Service scripts that come with it. And they work perfectly. I'm using these scripts on 12 Wildfly servers now without a problem.

Comment: I will try this. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I manage Wildfly on Windows:

- Open `Task Manager`
- Eanble `Command Line` column under `Details` tab
- Find `Wildfly` process (the path will tell you correct instance)
- Kill the process

Then the server starts through admin console. You can also kill Wildfly master process and start over.